# how to retrieve month current year and same month last year based on yyyymmdd

Tags: sql, date, reporting-services

is there a way I can retrieve the month this year and same month last year based on yyyymmdd? My report is comparing data from last year month and current year month. For example if yyyymmdd is 20180613 then I would like to have dates 20180601 to 20180613 and 20170601 to 20170613.

Would really appreciate all your advice and help I can get.

Thank you!

Comment: Which sql database engine are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using SQL 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server

You can try `Convert(type,datetime,112)` and `DATEADD`

```
declare @tdate DATETIME= CONVERT(DATETIME, '20180613', 112) ;
select CONVERT(nvarchar(20), sDate1, 112) sDate1,
    CONVERT(nvarchar(20), eDate1, 112) eDate1,
    CONVERT(nvarchar(20), sDate2, 112) sDate2,
    CONVERT(nvarchar(20), eDate2, 112) eDate2
from (
    SELECT DATEADD(day, - DAY ( @tdate ) + 1 ,  @tdate) sDate1,
        @tdate eDate1,
        DATEADD(year,-1,DATEADD(day, - DAY ( @tdate ) + 1 ,  @tdate)) sDate2,
        DATEADD(year,-1,@tdate) eDate2
)T;
```

---

**Result:**

```
sDate1               eDate1               sDate2               eDate2
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
20180601             20180613             20170601             20170613
```

---

[Test DEMO Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=805c22056165f0002423e9205efda976)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help IT WeiHan

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle -

Query -

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate),'yyyymmdd') as y1, to_char(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),'yyyymmdd') as y2, to_char(trunc(sysdate) + interval '-1' year,'yyyymmdd') as y3, to_char(trunc(sysdate,'mm') + interval '-1' year,'yyyymmdd') as y4 from dual;
```

Output -

```
"Y1","Y2","Y3","Y4"
"20180613","20180601","20170613","20170601"
```